# Create an automation for WhatsApp's chat app?

Tags: automator, whatsapp.app

I have the following code which uses the user's clipboard to WhatsApp's online API.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set text1 to the clipboard
    do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & text1
    return input
end run
```

Now I want to check if the number matches the international code to use in WhatsApp's API correctly.

For example, if I copied a number **021** 123456, I want to replace the first few digits with +994**021** 123456. What happened here is replace the first 0 with +994.
However if the number already starts with +994 then there is no need to amend it.

How do I create a code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out myself. Putting it out here if anyone needed it in the future.

```
 on run {input, parameters}
        set text1 to the clipboard
        if first character of text1 is "0" then
            set text2 to 1 - text1 as integer
            do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & "994" & 1 - text2
            return
        end if
        do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & text1
        return input
 end run
```

Comment: Replace `do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="` with `open location "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="`, which performs the same function without having to create a shell process to do it.  Also, as this is running within macOS, you can actually bypass the browser altogether, by using `open location "whatsapp://send?phone="`.

Comment: @CJK does this have any notable effects on the script?

Comment: Effects on the script include being shorter, easier-to-read, and will be something less likely to be earmarked as an obviously "novice" script. In terms of execution, it'll be faster and more reliable (`open location` is an AppleScript command, but `do shell script` calls the shell program `open`, which a shell function, alias or a variety of other things can redirect `open` to do something else. Also, if you want to just run a shell command, Automator has a Shell script action). Using the `whatsapp://` scheme instead of `https://` doesn't bring the browser up, and is a lot faster.

Comment: Also, your script here doesn't do what you stated you wanted to achieve in your question above.  I think what you want is this: `ignoring white space` // `set text item delimiters to {null, space, "+9940", "+994"}` // `"whatsapp://send?phone=994" & (text items of (the clipboard) as text as number as miles as text)` // `end`. This will trim off all leading zeroes and any instance of "+994" plus up to one zero after (if present), then prepend the URL and "994" . So `+99412555555`, `012555555`, and `+994012555555` all become `"whatsapp://send?phone=99412555555"`. `open location result` to finish.